# Seeking alternative to ERDAS Imagine?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, software-recommendations, geomatica

I am having trouble with the ArcGIS 10.1 and ERDAS Imagine 9.2 license conflict.
From what I found out it isn't that rare, but I do not understand why there such a conflict in the first place.

Therefore I am looking for some alternatives, heard about PCI's Geomatica but never tried it, any open source solutions?

Comment: What sort of trouble exactly? Are you using floating licenses?  If so, make sure each license manager has a different port number.

Comment: This looks like two questions: 1) "why is there such a conflict in the first place?" and 2) "looking for some alternatives, ..., any open source solutions?".  I recommend that you edit your Question to focus it on the second (because the Answers provided seem to be addressing that) and research/ask the first one separately.

Comment: What are the main image processing tasks that you use Erdas for?

Answer (score 7):

Erdas used to work together wih ESRI, but now it is ENVI that has joint its forces. I would therefore use ENVI for the compatibility.

But if you are looking for an good open source solution, I recommend Orfeo Toolbox (http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/ ). You can either use the library, the command line application or a complete GUI (called Monteverdi). Furthermore, there is a Python wrapper and it is even accessible through QGIS.

Comment: Thanks. What about Opticks, have you tried it? Interestingly enough even though they are open-source, they are not working together with OSGEO.

Comment: I didn't know Opticks and I am using OTB nearly everyday. From what I see on the user guide, the GUI for Opticks seems to be more developed than Monteverdi. However, for large data handling (global land cover mapping and time series analysis), OTB is really powerful.

Comment: Thank you again. I will be sure to try it. Also, I've seen somewhere that Orfeo is installed with QGIS, GRASS etc.

Answer (score 4):

For specific remote sensing tasks you could check out **[BEAM](http://www.brockmann-consult.de/cms/web/beam/)**.

If you are not afraid of command line, I would suggest a combination of GRASS (for storage and 
datahandling and analysis), QGIS(for visualization) and GDAL/OGR and **[pktools](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pktools)** (for analysis).
All these are open-source.

A very good instructional site is **[here](http://www.spatial-ecology.net/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aintroduction)**.

Answer (score 4):

GRASS GIS (open source, since version 6 with a [new graphical user interface](http://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/user-interface/)) offers
 [many image processing methods](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_processing) including:

- Import of all common satellite, aerial and UAV data formats
- Preprocessing

  - Geometric preprocessing/Georectification
  - Radiometric preprocessing
  - Correction for atmospheric effects
  - Correction for topographic/terrain effects
  - Cloud removal
- Image classification
- Image segmentation (see especially new [i.segment](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.segment.html) in GRASS GIS 7)
- Filtering
- Fourier Transform
- Canonical and Principal Component Analysis
- Texture analysis
- Spectral unmixing
- Thermal remote sensing
- [Time series analysis](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/temporalintro.html) (new in GRASS GIS 7)
- Image Enhancements

  - Radiometric Enhancements
  - Geometric Enhancements

    - Image Fusion
    - Pansharpening
  - Optimal channel selection for color composites
- Vegetation indices
- Stereo anaglyphs
- some [LiDAR](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR) support (incl. geocoding of 3D point clouds)
- and more...

Answer (score 2):

[Idrisi Selva](http://www.clarklabs.org/products/idrisi.cfm) through the Clark University Lab is an amazing alternative for image processing.  I think there are ArcGIS plug-ins for it as well.

Comment: Indeed, I have heard about Idrisi, but it's not the cheapest solution. Nevertheless, it is a worthy mention.